# coordinates not working after upgrade

Tags: 2sxc

I just upgraded `2sxc` to `09.08.00` and an app suddenly stopped working.
So what we called in the template was:

```
data-latitude='@Content.Lat.Replace(",",".")' 
data-longitude='@Content.Long.Replace(",",".")'
```

And that worked fine, but after the upgrade, it does not render the coordinates anymore, so in the source, I can see data-latitude data-longitude but no values.

Any ideas what I should change?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but there was an issue with numbers being zero instead of null when not set, causing side-effects. It will be fixed in 9.10 to be released next week. Please check that first, otherwise post your question again.